# Is it possible to set A javascript variable value to an elements id name using an onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

Hey this is my first time posting here I was wondering it it is possible to set a javascripts variable Value to an html elements id name when clicking on said html element

Example

```
<div id="01" onclick="Myfunction()"></div>
MyFunction(){
variable x = 01(Divs Id number)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `this.id` and pass `this`(current element) as argument

```js
function Myfunction(elem) {
  var x = elem.id; //Or this.getAttribute('id')
  console.log(x)
}
```

```html
<div id="01" onclick="Myfunction(this)">Click me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible  ... below is demo on this ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <script> 
         function Myfunction(ctrl){     
           var id= ctrl.id;
           var name= ctrl.name;      
           console.log(id);
           console.log(name);
           alert(id);
           alert(name);
         }
      </script>
      <div id="01" name='divOne' onclick="Myfunction(this)">div sample</div>
      <input id="02" type="number" name='txtOne' onclick="Myfunction(this)"></p>    
   </body>
</html>
```

Remember `only input types html controls can have name property`.. that's why `div` will return `undefined` on name ..